# First element in list/nested lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list, which can either be `list[]` or `list[][]`, and I want to get the very first actual element, which is either `list[0]` or `list[0][0]`. What would be the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: nothing pythonic here. just a for loop on the list.

Comment: @Adam won't I need an if statement the check if the list is nested?

Comment: u can do it with if or with try except block. see the answer.

Comment: Please update your question with the code with the if that you tried.

Comment: Is it always exactly 1D or 2D, never more? Is it always at least one element in both dimensions?

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes, either 1d or 2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
ls[0][0] if isinstance(ls[0], list) else ls[0]
```

This will return the `ls[0][0]` if `ls` containing a list in the first value else the first value of the `ls`.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested methods will work in your case, but let me suggest a more generic method:

```
elem = mylist
while type(elem) == list:
    elem = elem[0]
```

At the end of this loop,`elem` will contain the first element.

It will achieve the objective for even higher dimensional lists, or even non-list objects (it will just not run the loop at all).

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward approach is most Pythonic here:

```
elem = mylist[0]
if isinstance(elem, list):
    elem = elem[0]
```

If a dimension might be length zero, this will raise an `IndexError`, but that's probably what you want anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
try:
    print(l[0][0])
except:
    print(l[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this,

```
l1=[1]

try:
    a=l1[0][0]
    print("two diamensional")
except:
    print("one diamensional")
```

hope this helps you!